# Why is this displayed when I open the pvm file (saved from Parallel Desktop) with VMware fusion?

Tags: virtualization, parallels-desktop, vmware

There is an ARM Windows machine in my Parallel Desktop. Just now I tried to switch to VMware Fusion. I opened the pvm file with VMware Fusion and it was convert as a vmwarevm file then. Now I tied openning the vmwarevm but it displays "This virtual machine cannot be powered on because it requires the X86 machine architecture, which is incompatible with this Arm machine architecture host. See KB-84273."
[image: As shown in figure]

Comment: And what does KB-84273 say?

Comment: @MartinR KB-84273 said what I opened was an x86 virtual machine. However, I did open an ARM Windows virtual machine

Answer (score 2):

See VMWare's KB-84273: [Dealing with Multiple Machine Architectures (84273)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/84273):

> …
>
> **Attempting to run an operating system written for a particular machine architecture on a machine of a differing machine architcecture will result in errors.** One cannot run Windows 10 for X86_64 on an Arm machine or macOS for X86_64 on Apple silicon.
>
> Using virtual machines does not remove the operating system dependency on a machine architecture. A virtual machine that contains an X86_64 version of Linux will not work on a Arm or Apple silicon Macintosh; an Apple silicon version of macOS will not work on an X86_64 Mac.
>
> …

Comment: The question says that it was an ARM Windows in the origianl Parallels.

Comment: As mmmmmm said, I did opened an ARM Windows. This is the problem.

Comment: Have you [reported this behaviour](https://www.vmware.com/support/policies/defect.html) to VMWare?

Comment: I post a question in their community and get [an acceptable answer](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Why-is-this-displayed-when-I-open-the-pvm-file-saved-from/m-p/2948920/highlight/true#M181397). Thank you for recommending this website！

Answer (score 0):

I got clear answer M1 is ARM architecture which is not support intel based (x86_64) or AMD

so final verdict is to download ARM based iso and get your work done.
[image: Sample image for working ARM based iso]